# Implementing the ls command in C

Tags: c, linux, ls

I'm trying to implement the ls command in c with as many flags as possible, but i'm having issues with getting the correct Minor and Major of the files, here's an example of what i did.

```
> ls -l ~/../../dev/tty
crw-rw-rw- 1 root tty 5, 0 Nov 25 13:30
```

this is the normal ls command as you can see the Major is 5, and Minor is 0.
my program shows the following :

```
Minor: 6
Major: 0
```

i'm still a beginner so i didn't really understand the issue here, this is what i did so far (the program is not identical to the ls command yet, but only shows information about a file).

```
int disp_file_info(char **argv)
{
 struct stat sb;

 stat(argv[1], &sb);
 printf("Inode: %d\n", sb.st_ino);
 printf("Hard Links: %d\n", sb.st_nlink);
 printf("Size: %d\n", sb.st_size);
 printf("Allocated space: %d\n", sb.st_blocks);
 printf("Minor: %d\n", minor(sb.st_dev));
 printf("Major: %d\n", major(sb.st_dev));
 printf("UID: %d\n", sb.st_uid);
 printf("GID: %d\n", sb.st_gid);
 }
```

for now this is only to obtain certain information about a file, everything seems to be correct when compared with the ls command except for Minor and Major.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `st_dev`, which is the device on which the file *resides*. You want `st_rdev`, which is the device the special file "is"/represents. (You should first check whether the file is a device node, though.)

Comment: i did st_rdev instead of st_dev, and it works great thank you, do you mind explaining to me what is the difference please ?

Comment: Oh never mind, it's all in man 2 stat, i skipped the st_rdev part, sorry, thanks again :)

Comment: @James If you look at `man 2 stat`, you can see that `st_dev` is described as being the device on which that file is stored, whereas `st_rdev` is the "represented device" of that file… I don't really know how to explain it better than that. (edit: Ok, you found it yourself. =)

Comment: yes it's very clean now ^_^ thanks again, next time i won't be skipping parts of man description.